# WooCommerce Cart Page: Change position of checkout buttons

Tags: html, css, woocommerce

I want to change the position of the checkout buttons on the WooCommerce Cart Page. I want to have the green button (a.checkout-button.button.alt.wc-forward) below the Paypal Button. Can anyone help me?

[image]

Comment: Send me the page URL.

Comment: you can only reorder the payment options not checkout buttons

Comment: You can choose between Paypal check out, "Weiter zur Kasse" then you get to the checkout page and the Stripe payment Request Button

Comment: a.checkout-button.button.alt.wc-forward {
height: 46px !important;
border-radius: 4px;
line-height: 46px;
 
}

I already have this code

Comment: @Hans1234 So add this code in your question with some explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reorder them using flexbox. Try adding the following through Custom CSS:

```
.cart_totals .wc-proceed-to-checkout {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column; /* So that it preserves the vertical layout */
}

.wcppec-checkout-buttons {
   order: -1; /* This can vary according to other elements, play around the value */
}
```

**Output:**

[image]